# Realizar UPDATE a un array

Tags: php, mysql

Muy Buenas ...
Este es el código que hasta ahora tengo.

```
<input type="hidden" name="orden" value="<?php echo $orden;    ?>">   
<div id="contenedor">
<label><h3>Selecciona la Empresa que se le asignará la Orden</h3> </label>   
<select id="cliente" name="cliente" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <option></option>
            <?php
            require('../terceros/conecta.php');
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM cliente';
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
                echo "<option value='".$row['cod_cliente'].",".$row['documento'].",".$row['direccion'].",".$row['tipo_cliente']."'>".$row['r_social']."</option>";
            }
            mysqli_close($con);    
            ?>
        </select>
```

envío un input `type="hidden"` con un código y también el array del select

Este es el código y lo que deseo es hacer un `UPDATE` el cual logicamente llevará un `WHERE` que es el que se envía por input `type="hidden"`

Este es el codigo para realizar UPDATE a una tabla que ya previamente se le cargaron algunos datos.

```
$ced = $_POST['cliente'];
$num_fac = $_POST['orden'];
//$estado_fac = $_POST['estado_fac'];

for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($ced); $i++){

$actualiza= mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE servicio SET documento='$num_fac', cod_cliente='$estado_fac', direccion='$estado_fac', tipo_cliente='tipo_cliente' WHERE orden_serv_hm='$orden[$i]' ");
  }
}

if ($actualiza == true){

  echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Datos de Facturación Ingresados Correctamente'); window.location='factura_dinamica.php'; </script>";
}
else{

   echo "No Se actualizo correctamente";
}
      mysqli_close($conexion);    

?>
```

Pero este es el error que me sale.

No Se actualizo correctamente

```
// $campos=array('cod_cliente', 'documento', 'direccion', 'tipo_cliente', 'r_social' ); // $campos2=array($_POST['cod_cliente'], $_POST['documento'], $_POST['direccion'], $_POST['tipo_cliente']); // for($i=0; $i<2; $i++) // { // mysql_query("update tabla set ".$documento[$i]."= '".$direccion[$i]."' where id = '".$orden['id']."' ", $conexion) or die(mysql_error()); // } if(!$stmt->execute()){ $arrResult['error'] = "El Ingreso de factura que desea realizar no es permitido. ".$conexion->error; }else{ /*Esto es sólo un gadget :) */ $totalInsert=$stmt->affected_rows; $mensaje=($totalInsert > 0) ? "Se ha insertado correctamente" : "No fue posible la inserción. Error: ".$stmt->error; $arrResult['mensaje'] = $mensaje; echo""; } } ?>
```

Este es la ultima modificacion que le hago al codigo ya que en otros me quitaba datos de la tabla.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema? Yo no veo ningún `UPDATE`

Comment: Como comenta A.Cedano, no se ve ningún update. Por otra parte te animaría a mejorar la pregunta, ya que:
- Realizar UPDATE a un array
¿Quieres actualizar un array?¿Quieres realizar un update a partir de un array? :/
- Al final comentas "deseo hace un update", que llevará where (otra cosa). ¿Hacer algo nuevo pero que lo haga distinto?
Sintentizando, primero haz lo nuevo y luego modificas lo creado.
Quizás fue al expresarte, pero le falta algo de sentido a esta pregunta
:)

Comment: @A.Cedano jajaja amigo si es ahí donde está el tema no lo se hacer, el que tengo no me funciona, esta es una estructura que estoy intentando pero nada.

$campos=array('cod_cliente', 'documento', 'direccion', 'tipo_cliente', 'r_social' ); 
$campos2=array($_POST['cod_cliente'], $_POST['documento'], $_POST['direccion'], $_POST['tipo_cliente']); 
    for($i=0; $i<2; $i++) 
    { 
mysql_query("update tabla set ".$documento[$i]."= '".$direccion[$i]."' where id = '".$orden['id']."' ", $conexion) or die(mysql_error()); 
}

Comment: eso debe ir en la pregunta. y que error recibis?

Comment: @gbianchi compañero nada, no veo muestra en un evento y mientras hago modificaciones me elimina los demás datos ya previamente cargados

Comment: Como que elimina? podes explicar bien que pasa, pulsa el boton [edit] y aclara todo lo que pasa.

Comment: @gbianchi será que en esta oportunidad si logré hacerme entender ? de antemano a todos Mil gracias. Excelente.

Comment: El problema es que la pregunta sigue sin entenderse. Además creo que por desconocimiento o por miedo a aprender nuevas tecnologías te estás complicando la vida. En otra pregunta te hablé de Ajax y además te puse un ejemplo muy concreto sobre cómo desde Ajax puedes hacer varias llamadas al servidor y consultar / insertar / actualizar datos sin tener que recurrir a procedimientos oscuros y confusos como el uso de input hidden, redirecciones desde PHP a Javascript, etc, etc. Ajax es muy fácil de aprender y de implementar. Es cierto que al principio tiene una sintaxis fea, pero eso es lo de menos.

Answer (score -1):

Por empezar hay un tema con el uso de las comillas en tu siguiente instruccion:

```
"UPDATE servicio SET documento='$num_fac', cod_cliente='$estado_fac', direccion='$estado_fac', tipo_cliente='tipo_cliente' WHERE orden_serv_hm='$orden[$i]' "
```

yo concatenaria con puntos porque probablemente te este fallando por intentar mandar un string a un campo numerico

```
"UPDATE servicio SET documento='".$num_fac."', cod_cliente='".$estado_fac."', direccion='".$estado_fac."', tipo_cliente='tipo_cliente' WHERE orden_serv_hm='".$orden[$i]."' "
```

Comment: No hace falta concatenar con punto. PHP si la cadena de texto está delimitada por comillas dobles, buscará dentro de ella variables y las sustituirá por su valor ([documentación oficial](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)). Para tu solución (que aún así creo que no es correcta) bastaría con añadir las comillas simples, quedando así: `"UPDATE servicio SET documento='$num_fac' cod_cliente='$estado_fac' , direccion='$estado_fac' , tipo_cliente='tipo_cliente' WHERE orden_serv_hm='$orden[$i]' `

Comment: Esto llega por POST
Array ( [orden] => 100022 [cliente] => 10002,8020114266,CARRERA 49C 74-12,ARL [continuar] => )

Esto es lo que me comentan para intentar.
$num_orden = $_POST['orden'];
$detalle_cliente = $_POST['cliente'];

for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($num_orden); $i++){

$stmt= mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE servicio SET cod_cliente='$detalle_cliente', documento='$detalle_cliente',  direccion='$detalle_cliente', tipo_cliente='$detalle_cliente', r_social='$detalle_cliente' WHERE orden_serv_hm='".$num_orden[$i]."' ");
  }
}
Pero aún no logro actualizar los campos en ese tabla.